# Why my home page doesnt work?

Tags: pages, homepage

I migrated my website from one hosting to another by importing the DB and reinstalling the old exported DB on the new hosting. I have also re-installed the wordpress template. The result is the following:

https://www.sea-dobbiaco.bz.it/

The original home page is as follows, and on the old hosting it worked well. 
https://goodnews.xplodedthemes.com/news-flash/?xt-preview

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

On your site you can see things like

```
    [vc_row xt_pattern_opacity=”100″ xt_bg_repeat=”repeat-y” xt_text_scheme=”lighter- 
    overlay”][vc_column width=”2/3″ css=”.vc_custom_1440884085800{padding-right: 0px  
    !important;padding-left: 0px !important;}”][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner]
```

It show that your theme is using Visual composer plugin but it is not activated so you have got to upload it and activate it.

Comment: I installed the plug in but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is caused by the .htaccess file in the themes folder. Also, there might be some wrong Apache Directives that is causing issue with the themes folder in upstream .htaccess files. You should check if there is permission conflicting redirection loops or aliases. You should also check the permissions on the themes folder.